# How to convert enum into a key,value array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, enums, casting

```
var enums = {
  '1': 'HELLO',
  '2' : 'BYE',
  '3' : 'TATA'
  };
```

I want to be able to convert that into an array that looks like this,

```
[
  {
    number:'1',
    word:'HELLO'
  },
  {
    number:'2',
    word:'BYE'
  },
  {
    number:'3',
    word:'TATA'
  }
]
```

all of the solutions I see form an array of either the keys or the values.

Comment: What is `{'1', 'HELLO'}`?  It is neither valid JavaScript nor valid TypeScript.

Comment: Why do you expect `{number:'2', word: 'TATA'}`?

Comment: @jcalz obviously a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative is to use a [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate over the `enums` keys and construct your desired array of objects.

```js
var enums = {
  '1': 'HELLO',
  '2' : 'BYE',
  '3' : 'TATA'
};

let res = [];

for (key in enums)
{
    res.push({number: key, word: enums[key]});    
}

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 13):

You could map the entries with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var enums = { 1: 'HELLO', 2: 'BYE', 3: 'TATA' },
    objects = Object.entries(enums).map(([number, word]) => ({ number, word }));

console.log(objects);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to desired format

```js
var enums = {
  '1': 'HELLO',
  '2' : 'BYE',
  '3' : 'TATA'
  };
  
let op = Object.entries(enums).map(([key, value]) => ({ number:key, word:value }))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: how do you know this the expected output?

Comment: @brk this is specified in question mate. `I want to be able to convert that into an array that looks like this,`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
This gives me the output 
[ { "1": "HELLO" }, { "2": "BYE" }, { "3": "TATA" } ]

I need it to be [ { "1","HELLO" }, { "2","BYE" }, { "3","TATA" } ]
, instead of the :

Comment: @user7434041 can you describe the datatype you expect? `{ "1","HELLO" }` is not valid javascript or typescript. it almost looks like a python tuple

Comment: @user7434041 in object you need key/value pair, in this format --> `key:value`.

Comment: Oops sorry my bad, editing the expected output in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.keys and map

```js
var obj = {
  '1': 'HELLO',
  '2' : 'BYE',
  '3' : 'TATA'
};


const result = Object.keys(obj).map(el => {
  return {
    number: el,
    word: obj[el]
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Need to create an object of Map type then get the value using get
>   method like outData.get("1")

```
var obj = {
    '1': 'HELLO',
    '2': 'BYE',
    '3': 'TATA'
};
var outData = new Map();
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (e) {
    outData.set(e, obj[e])
});
```

**To get data use outData.get("key")**

Now the out put data will like-

```
Map(3) {"1" => "HELLO", "2" => "BYE", "3" => "TATA"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with foreach and push it to an array like this

```js
var enums = {
    '1': 'HELLO',
    '2' : 'BYE',
    '3' : 'TATA'
    };

var enumArray = []
Object.entries(enums).forEach(([key, value]) => enumArray.push({number : key, word : value}));

console.log(enumArray);
```

Comment: this will give you all key and value combinations resulting in wrong number of array objects E.G https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMgggZQCoH0ByBVAsgIQKIBKKA8gGIpICSWeUA3gFBTOyKoBsADCgCJwCaCKAF4oXADRMW8ZCgDM3PoJFQFklq1kBGAKy8BQ0bvXS2KLSgDqePAGkVAdhPMZqC0pVbJAXwbEARgBWwADGAC4AdKBhAE4AlsAAzgAUrujY+ERkFNR4AJQREACGAA7JyQDaANbAAJ7iUABuRQA2YMAAunkiAHxQyXRxACYAXFA19U2t7WPNbcDeeXkMQA